# Why do scipy and numpy fft plots look different?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I am currently doing some spectrum analysis for a piece of coursework, though we haven't been explicitly taught Fourier transforms yet. I have been playing around with the various fft algorithms in scipy and numpy on some data that I know what the answer should look like

In this case its an AM signal at 8kHz carrier frequency and 1kHz modulated sine wave on top so should have 3 clear peaks on an fft

When applying `scipy.fftpack.rfft` and `numpy.fft.rfft` I get the following plots respectively:

**Scipy:**

[image]

**Numpy:**

[image]

While the shape of the 2 FFTs are roughly the same with the correct ratios between the peaks, the `numpy` one looks much smoother, whereas the `scipy` one has slightly smaller max peaks, and has much more noise.

I'm assuming this is largely down to different applications of a Discrete Fourier Transform algorithm, and have seen other articles about how the `scipy` implementation is faster in run time. But I was wandering what it is that specifically causes the difference, and which one is actually more accurate?

EDIT: Code used to generate plots:

```
data = pd.read_csv("./Waveforms/AM waveform Sine.csv", sep = ',', dtype = float)

data = data.as_matrix()
time = data[:,0]
voltage = data[:,1]/data[:,1].max() # normalise the values

#scipy plot:
plt.figure()
magnitude =  scipy.fftpack.rfft(voltage)
freq = scipy.fftpack.rfftfreq(len(time),np.diff(time)[0])
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, np.absolute(magnitude), lw = 1)
plt.ylim(0,2500)
plt.xlim(0,15)

#numpy plot
magnitude = np.fft.rfft(voltage)
freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(len(time),np.diff(time)[0])

plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, np.absolute(magnitude), lw = 1)
plt.ylim(0,2500)
plt.xlim(0,15)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From NumPy's doc for [rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html#numpy.fft.rfft):

> Returns:
>
> out : complex ndarray
>
> The truncated or zero-padded input, transformed along the axis
>   indicated by axis, or the last one if axis is not specified. If n is
>   even, the length of the transformed axis is (n/2)+1. If n is odd, the
>   length is (n+1)/2.

It is not written explicitly but the "transformed data" is here complex.

From SciPy's doc for [rfft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.rfft.html#scipy.fftpack.rfft)

> z : real ndarray
>
> The returned real array contains:
>
> ```
> [y(0),Re(y(1)),Im(y(1)),...,Re(y(n/2))]              if n is even
> [y(0),Re(y(1)),Im(y(1)),...,Re(y(n/2)),Im(y(n/2))]   if n is odd
> ```

Conclusion: the storage is different.

For a starter, look at the length of `magnitude`, it will be different in both cases. I give an example below for clarity:

```
In [33]: data = np.random.random(size=8)

In [34]: np.fft.rfft(data)
Out[34]: 
array([ 3.33822983+0.j        ,  0.15879369+0.48542266j,
        0.00614876+0.03590621j, -0.67376592-0.69793372j,  1.51730861+0.j        ])

In [35]: scipy.fftpack.rfft(data)
Out[35]: 
array([ 3.33822983,  0.15879369,  0.48542266,  0.00614876,  0.03590621,
       -0.67376592, -0.69793372,  1.51730861])
```

The first element in both cases is the so-called "DC component" (the mean of the signal).

Then, you can recognize in the SciPy version the succession of real and imaginary parts of the NumPy version.

Comment: How does a different storage implementation cause different shaped plots though? As by the looks of your example the exact same data is stored numerically, just in a different format?

Comment: Storing the complex values in successive elements of the array means that the operation of `np.absolute` on the array `magnitude` will in the `np.fft.rfft` case give the norm of the complex values (which is the relevant physical quantity) while for the `scipy.fftpack.rfft` case it will give the absolute value of first the real part of the number, then the magnitude of the complex component only, and the result of these two operations is different.